# Replace first 3 occurrences of a character in each line

Tags: sed, replace, bioinformatics, text-processing

I have a tab-delimited file of genetic variants with an `INFO` column of many semicolon-delimited tags:

```
Chr Start   End Ref Alt ExAC_ALL    ExAC_AFR    ExAC_AMR    ExAC_EAS    ExAC_FIN    ExAC_NFE    ExAC_OTH    ExAC_SAS    Otherinfo   QUAL    DP  Chr Start       Ref Alt QUAL    FILTER  INFO
1   15847952    15847952    G   C   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   241.9   76196   1   15847952    .   G   C   241.9   PASS    AC=2;AF=0;AN=18332;BaseQRankSum=0.731;ClippingRankSum=-0.731;DP=76196;ExcessHet=3.1;FS=0;InbreedingCoeff=-0.0456;MLEAC=2;MLEAF=0;MQ=38.93;MQRankSum=0.515;NEGATIVE_TRAIN_SITE;QD=10.52;ReadPosRankSum=0.89;SOR=0.481;VQSLOD=-1.406        culprit=MQ
1   15847963    15847963    A   C   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   1607.1  126156  1   15847963    .   A   C   1607.1  PASS    AC=2;AF=0;AN=22004;BaseQRankSum=0.851;ClippingRankSum=-0.419;DP=126156;ExcessHet=3.4904;FS=0;InbreedingCoeff=0.0299;MLEAC=2;MLEAF=0;MQ=59.29;MQRankSum=0.18;QD=1.55;ReadPosRankSum=0.067;SOR=0.651;VQSLOD=0.995        culprit=QD
1   15847964    15847966    GCC -   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   1607.1  126156  1   15847963    .   AGCC    A   1607.1  PASS    AC=63;AF=0.003;AN=22004;BaseQRankSum=0.851;ClippingRankSum=-0.419;DP=126156;ExcessHet=3.4904;FS=0;InbreedingCoeff=0.0299;MLEAC=55;MLEAF=0.002;MQ=59.29;MQRankSum=0.18;QD=1.55;ReadPosRankSum=0.067;SOR=0.651;VQSLOD=0.995        culprit=QD
1   15847978    15847978    C   T   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   648.41  234344  1   15847978    .   C   T   648.41  PASS    AC=9;AF=0;AN=25894;BaseQRankSum=-0.572;ClippingRankSum=-0.404;DP=234344;ExcessHet=3.348;FS=2.639;InbreedingCoeff=-0.0098;MLEAC=6;MLEAF=0;MQ=58.71;MQRankSum=-0.456;NEGATIVE_TRAIN_SITE;QD=4.13;ReadPosRankSum=-0.456;SOR=0.452;VQSLOD=-1.238        culprit=QD
```

I want to split the first 3 semicolon-delimited terms in the INFO column:

```
AC=2;AF=0;AN=18332
```

So that they become:

```
AC=2    AF=0    AN=18332    BaseQRankSum=0.731;ClippingRankSum=-0.731;DP=76196;ExcessHet=3.1;FS=0;InbreedingCoeff=-0.0456;MLEAC=2;MLEAF=0;MQ=38.93;MQRankSum=0.515;NEGATIVE_TRAIN_SITE;QD=10.52;ReadPosRankSum=0.89;SOR=0.481;VQSLOD=-1.406        culprit=M
```

So far I've tried the following expression with `sed`:

```
sed -i .bk 's/\(A.=.*\);/\1        /g' allChr_ExAC38.hg38_multianno.txt
```

But this yields no changes.

Ideally I was looking for a way to tell `sed` to replace the first 3 occurences of a semicolon `;` for a `tab`, but `'s/;/      /g3'` doesn't seem to mean that.

Comment: What is the `.bk` in your command `sed -i .bk [...]`?

Comment: @lubgr: Backup extension.

Comment: If you are familiar with R, then try this function from *vcfR* package: `INFO2df(x)`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Perl instead of sed:

```
perl -i.bk -pe '$c = 0; s/;/\t/ while $c++ < 3' -- file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this awk

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<4;i++)sub(";","\t")}1' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '
FNR==1{
  print;
  next}
{
  num=split($(NF-1),array,";");
  for(i=4;i<=num;i++){
    val=val?val ";"array[i]:array[i]};
    $(NF-1)=array[1] OFS array[2] OFS array[3] OFS val;
    val="";
    $1=$1
}
1
' OFS="\t"  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.*` in your regex is greedy, and will match as much text as possible on the line, up to just before the last semicolon (but not beyond, because then the entire regex won't match at all).

You cannot mix `/3` and `/g`; the latter means, replace *all* occurrences on every line, so it is directly at odds with the `/3` which says to replace only a maximum of three occurrences on a line.

"No changes" seems wrong, though; if your regex matched at all, the last semicolon on matching lines will have been replaced.

Some regex engines support non-greedy matching, but `sed` isn't one of them. As long as there is a single delimiter character you can use to limit the greediness, using that is a much better solution anyway. In your case, simply replace `.` with `[^;]` to say "any character except (newline or) semicolon" instead of "any character (except newline)."

```
sed 's/\(A.=[^;]*\);/\1        /3' allChr_ExAC38.hg38_multianno.txt
```

(This will print to standard output for verification; put back the `-i .bk` once you see the result is correct.)

Based on your example data, perhaps consider replacing the remaining `.` in the expression with `[A-Z]` and `[^;]` with `[^;=]` or even `[0-9]`. The more specific you can make your regex, the better.

Comment: Some of the `sed` constructs here are not entirely portable. If this doesn't work, perhaps update your question with precise information about your platform (Mac? Linux distro? Windows? (shudder)) and which version of its `sed` package you have.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i.bak 's/;/\n/3;h;y/;/\t/;G;s/\n.*\n/\t/' file
```

Replace the third `;` with a newline, make a copy of the line, replace all `;`'s with `\t`'s, append the copy and replace the end of the first line to the middle of the second line with a `\t`.

Since by definition a line is demarcated by a newline, lines cannot contain a newline unless they are introduced by a programmer.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of occurrences is reasonable you can pipe sed multiple times i.e.

`sed -E -e 's/[0-9]{4}/****/'| sed -E -e 's/[0-9]{4}/****/'| sed -E -e 's/[0-9]{4}/****/'`

will mask first 3 4-digit groups of credit card number like so

```
Input:
1234 5678 9101 1234  

Output:
**** **** **** 1234
```